# Не удается распарсить response body (строка в json) в spring cloud contract

Tags: java, spring-boot

Есть такой контракт

```
org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract.make {
    request {
        method 'GET'
        url ('test/token') {
            queryParameters {
                parameter("token", "jwt_==")
            }
        }
        headers {
            contentType('application/json')
        }
    }
    response {
        status 200
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
        body([
                responseElement: $(producer(regex("blabla=")))
        ])
    }
}
```

Который падает с ошибкой

```
com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Filter: [?] can not be applied to primitives. Current context is: blabla=
```

Что стоит отправить в респонз боди?

а) `body("blabla")` отдает `expected:<"[blabla]"> but was:<"["blabla"]">`

б) если писать `body("[\"blabla\"]")` -> `com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Filter: [?] can not be applied to primitives. Current context is: blabla`

в) `body('blabla')` приводит к `expected:<"[blabla]"> but was:<"["blabla"]">`

Comment: В результате выпадает неверный запрос

Comment: Как тогда будет правильно?